# MySql query distinct condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table structure

```
yymm | orderid | itemid | price | qty | status
2011 | 123456  | ABC    | 100   | 1   | completed
2011 | 123456  | DEF    | 200   | 1   | completed
2010 | 112233  | ABC    | 100   | 1   | cancelled
2010 | 112233  | DEF    | 200   | 1   | cancelled
```

I want to know how many distinct order that completed and cancelled
I come up with this query, but this is not distinct

```
select date,
COUNT(IF(status = 'completed', 1, NULL)) AS completed,
COUNT(IF(status = 'cancelled', 1, NULL)) AS cancelled
from my_table
GROUP BY date
order by date
```

How to calculate distinct order?

The expected result is

```
date | completed | cancelled
2011 | 1         | 0
2010 | 0         | 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count(distinct)`:

```
select date,
       count(distinct case when status = 'completed' then orderid end) AS completed,
       count(distinct case when status = 'cancelled' then orderid end) AS cancelled
from my_table
group by date
order by date;
```

I prefer `case` over `if()` because `case` is the SQL standard for conditional logic.

Comment: thanks i was wrongly put distinct inside like this COUNT(IF(status = 'completed', distinct orderid, NULL))

Answer (score 0):

OR,

```
select count(distinct order_id), date
from my_table
where status in ('completed','cancelled')
GROUP BY date
order by date
```